# How to install .apk in Blackberry 10.2?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

As you are aware that Blackberry 10.2 supports the installation of Android apps directly onto the phone.

I was wondering will the same supports for Hybrid Android application created IBM Worklight 6.2.

The following are the tools that I have used.

1. IBM Worklight 6.2,
2. BlackBerry 10.2[Latest update] - Z3 device &
3. APK built with Kitkat SDK version and also signed.

I have copied the Hello.apk into device storage and tried to install.

Installation was successful but **"Unfortunately, Hello was stopped"** when I launch the app.

Please help me to understand whether my understanding is wrong or should I follow an alternate way.

Comment: What is the output of logs?

Comment: As I told that I installed from device memory I couldn't capture the log.

Comment: @Karikalan, If my answer helped you solve this issue, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following blog post which provides step-by-step instructions on how to install Worklight-based Android apps (.apk files) in a device running BlackBerry OS 10.2.x.

IBM Worklight blog: [Installing worklight android apk files into BlackBerry 10.2.1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/installing_worklight_android_apk_files_into_blackberry_10_2_1?lang=en)

From the post

---

**Pre-requisites:**

- Install the SUN JRE 32 bit edition and set the bin folder to the path.
- Download and Install the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK from the below link (This is required to install the debug tokens on the device): http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/
- Download the Command Line tools for windows and BlackBerry 10.2.1 Simulator for windows from: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_runtime_release_notes.html/
- Unzip the developer tools to a directory
- Install the Worklight studio with ADT Plugin into Eclipse.
- Set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the Android SDK.
- BlackBerry Device (10.2.1 onwards) should be configured with the developer token.

**Deploying Android APK file into BlackBerry Devices**

- Generate the worklight Android APK file (Either Hybrid and Native Projects)
- Go to  the BlackBerry Command line tools directory
- Run the following command to generate the bar file from the apk. It will generate the bar file in the same location of apk file.

  ```
  apk2bar –d <DEBUG_TOKEN_FILE_PATH> <APK_FILE_PATH>
  ```
- Run the following command to deploy the bar file into BlackBerry device to test the application.

  ```
  batchbar-deploy <FOLDER_CONTIANING_BAR_FILES> <device_ip> <device_password>
  ```
- To Distribute the application sign the repackaged app with the command below:

  ```
  batchbar-signer <input_files> <developer_certificate>  <keystore_password> [<csk_password>]    [-t <output_folder>]
  ```